# Meteor Vuejs. [Vue warn]: Error in destroyed hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null"

Tags: meteor, vue.js

I have installed the latest version of meteor -vue in linux (linuxmint 18.3) and in windows (8.1)
I am running this example: [meteor-vuetify](https://github.com/ackzell/meteor-vuetify)

In the javascript console (ctrl-shift-j) I get pages and pages with these 2 errors:

- [Vue warn]: Error in destroyed hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach'
  of null"
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

I get these, or similar errors in any app I develop. 
I am getting crazy.

[image]

Comment: it looks like you're trying to iterate over an array/object that no longer exists. Can you show the `destroyed` hook code?

Comment: It happens in every app I develop. No idea how to solve it. That's why I have posted a sample app I found online so it's very easy to reproduce the error. The "error on destroyed hook" is weird.

Comment: you might want to look into some of the vue-meteor activation/deactivation options https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor-tracker#activating-and-deactivating-meteor-data

Comment: Hi. I added those 2 methods but it didn't help. Thanks. I wish the documentation explained anything.